# Visualizing OData/REST metadata into a UML/Database Diagram

Tags: rest, odata, uml, metadata, edmx

I have access to a particular OData service (and metadata), but not the code behind building that service.  I'm using REST Clients like Postman to test the service and view its metadata.  However, the service is quite large and I am having trouble trying to figure out how all the different entities relate to each other. Visualizing the EDMX metadata into a sort of UML Class (database) Diagram would be extremely helpful in this case.

Being able to visualize all the different entities, keys, and relationships in a large service would be very helpful in both debugging that service and developing front-end code against it.

In my "non-data service" development, I use the Entity Framework within Visual Studio, which displays the EDMX file as a UML Diagram.  I tried manually plugging in the metadata from the service into a Visual Studio EDMX file but to no avail:  `The Entity Model Designer is unable to display the file you requested`

Is there a way to translate EDMX metadata in UML schema or entities relations schema ?

Comment: Have you read the page explaining how to ask a question ? Here we do not recommand tool ... I guess that your question will be deleted.

Comment: In the "What Topics can I ask here" section, "software tools commonly used by programmers" is on the list.  While questions to recommend a tool are off-topic because it draws opinions and spam, I"m just looking for a solution to visualized EDMX files provided by OData $metadata.  I changed to word "tool" to "something" to make that more clear.

Comment: @Peters I can not answer to this question, I do not exactly understand why it is not possible to discuss about a tool peacefully but this is the rule ...

Comment: Thanks for the comments @granier.  I appreciate the feedback and reworded the question based on StackOverflow's guidelines to not mention software tools or recommendations.  Now I believe I have a valid Problem/Solution question of "I have a large EDMX file from an OData service, is there a better way to view it".

Comment: Duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28274141/tool-to-visualise-odata-webapi-wcf-data-service

Answer (score 1):

The EDMX format that you receive from the $metadata endpoint of an OData service is NOT compatible with the EDMX format that is used by Visual Studio's Entity Framework. That is why you cannot open it in EDM Designer of VS.

The only tools I found so far that claim to visualize OData metadata are SparxSystems' Enterprise Architect and an online tool called [XOData](https://pragmatiqa.com/xodata/) (which seems to be at least partially broken).

Comment: defunct,  you can't pay for a license even if you tried